# Web site and API connection

Tags: web, design-patterns

If we make use of some API connection in our code, we cannot be sure that it will always respond ( it can go down because of DDoS or simply because of maintenance ). Then our website will not respond as expected because it depends on that API. What can we do to prevent that? Can we make a thread and tell the method if n time passes, return Math random, for example? What is a good practice?

```
int random() {
int x = /api call/;
return x;
}
```

Comment: A `try/catch` block should do the trick.

Comment: What to put in this try/catch block ?

Comment: Try the call, catch the error.

Comment: I am not talking about an error here. What I meant is that the API timed out, or it just takes too long to respond. Thus there should be some condition that surrounds this case, maybe use other functionality which is not as good, but is perhaps guaranteed to always work. I was asking if my method is good and if there is any other good approach, I think kind of know how to deal if there is an error in the API call.